# Disable hidden form input

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form kinda like this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 <select name="phase">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
 </select>
 <div data-phase="1">
  <input type="text" name="info" />
 </div>
 <div data-phase="2">
  <input type="text" name="info" />
 </div>
 <div data-phase="3">
  <input type="text" name="info" />
 </div>
</form>
```

By using JQuery, at any time, only one of the DIVs is displayed, corresponding to the value in the select box.

The issue is that the value POSTed is overridden by the last text input, since they all have the same name. Is there away around this WITHOUT renaming the inputs?

Comment: herm...in that case create the input from javascript. Create an event handler within the select box. Then depending on the value selected you inject that input box to the appropriate div.

Comment: This is what names like `info[]` are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- before submission, dynamically remove the unwanted `div` sections.  You could do this by hooking in using jQuery's `submit()` function callback.

To remove the elements, you could use jQuery's `remove()` function, for example.  It would be easier with `div` ids, but you could also use indexes to do it.

Comment: didn't think of that. I like this approach cuz it should be a one-liner for me. Thanks!

Comment: Later on, I will need to add a 'hidden' type input, so I ended up doing `$("#myform").submit(function(){$("input[type!='hidden']").filter(":hidden").remove(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically rename the inputs with javascript before submitting the form. Or you could even remove the disabled inputs from the DOM just before submission.

For example, something like this may work:

```
$(input[name="info"]).filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == "none";
}).remove();
```

So, select all the inputs named "info" that have display: none and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I so sorry to say this: you'll have to rename the name of each div. something like this
name="info1" name="info2" name="info3"
you only use the same name for the name attribute when you dealing with radio input type.